# I am importing a variable file in every sass module would it affect my css bundle size?

Tags: css, sass, css-modules, react-css-modules, sass-modules

- I am using `sass` mixed with `sass modules` to scope styles for each component
- I found myself importing the variables file at every sass module
- I import by the new `"@use"`

> would that make my final compiled css bundle bigger or sass handles it under the hood ?

> > also is there a better practice than adding the two lines importing the variables and mixins at every sass module it gets repetitive.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer first question:
Compiled bundle size won't be bigger. SASS resolve variable references under the hood to map the values.(per my understanding with SASS ways of working)

To answer your second question:
Try to have a look at the SMACSS on how to structure your presentation code. You can apply that structure to scss as well.

For e.g. essentials variables/mixins/extends can be clubbed in a utility file like _dependencies.scss and then include this one file rather including n number of imports.